# Does Nuget Versioning ignore + notation of build number SemVer?

Tags: version, nuget, nuget-package

Ref: 
[Nuget Versioning](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning)
[SemVer](http://semver.org/)

The nuget versioning documentation reads:

> SemVer also introduces the concept of a build number for those creating daily or continous builds. This is not supported in the public NuGet.org gallery.

It says it's not supported in nuget.org gallery but i'm wondering specifically how `nuget.exe -update` or `-install` or the Package Console in VS handles it...

Comment: What would you be trying to specify in `nuget.exe -update|install` if you can not pack or push a package to the gallery with a build number in the version?

Comment: well just like there's support for the dash notation "-beta" = pre-release.. for example, when i push a nuget with version = 1.0.1-rc it will show as a pre-release nuget and therefore all the logic around safe updates still takes place. I'd like to be able to push a version that looks like this:   1.0.1+421.500 and i was wondering if this would work?, crash nuget?, ignore everything after +?, treat it as a pre-release?

Comment: The NuGet team is working on supporting SemVer v2, but for now they only support SemVer v1. VS 2015 was released with NuGet v3, but unfortunately they didn't manage to include SemVer v2 as part of the v3 release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`SemanticVersion.cs`](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2/blob/861741bd780225a542c73a1d0904dd33b33a7a3d/src/Core/SemanticVersion.cs#L18) in the [Nuget codebase](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2). This provides the following regex to validate the provided version. If the regex doesn't match, the version is invalid:

```cs
new Regex(@"^(?<Version>\d+(\s*\.\s*\d+){0,3})(?<Release>-[a-z][0-9a-z-]*)?$", 
            RegexOptions.Compiled 
          | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase 
          | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```

The format for the prerelease string strictly has to start with a dash, then a letter, then any combination of dashes and alphanumerics. No `+` or `.` allowed.

Try and `pack` with anything other than a valid version and you will get:

```
Attempting to build package from 'ConsoleApplication1.csproj.nuspec'.
'1.0.1+421.500' is not a valid version string. 
Parameter name: version
```

If you've somehow got a package with an invalid version, then the nuget packaging process must have been bypassed and I can only assume attempting to push it will have unpredictable results.